# how to display labels in a BarChart for each bar using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I wanted to display the category of each value in the BarChart but it seems as though all categories get displayed on top of each other like the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxRry.png)

```
String query = "";
String destination = "";
try{
if(classe.isSelected()){
    PreparedStatement tableToGraph = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT  libelle_classe,avg(numseance) FROM Absence JOIN Etudiant on Etudiant.id_etudiant=Absence.id_etudiantA Join Classe on Etudiant.id_classeE=Classe.id_classe Group by libelle_classe"
    );
    ResultSet resultSet = tableToGraph.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<Double> numseance = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> libelle_classe = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        libelle_classe.add(resultSet.getString(1));
        numseance.add(resultSet.getDouble(2));
    }
    resultSet.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < numseance.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(libelle_classe.get(i));
    }
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> dataSeries = new XYChart.Series();
    /*CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Libelle Classe");
    CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("Avg des absences");*/
    dataSeries.setName("Taux d'Absenteisme pour chaque classe");
    for (int i = 0; i < numseance.size(); i++) {
        dataSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(libelle_classe.get(i), numseance.get(i)));
    }
    income_data.getData().add(dataSeries);
```

Comment: that's a bug (don't have the issue id handy, though) - afair, it should be fixed in a current version of fx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `setCategories` method from the `CategoryAxis` class?

```
CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
xAxis.setLabel("Libelle Classe");
xAxis.setCategories(libelle_classe);
income_data.getData().add(dataSeries);
```